# dialog preventing javascript audio

Tags: javascript, dialog, html5-audio

I am using the javascript Audio object to play an mp3

```
var myAudio = new Audio('alarm.mp3');
myAudio.play();
```

This works fine if I don't have a dialog. But if I add one

```
var response = confirm("press ok if you are awake");
```

Then playback stops until I close the dialog window. Is there a way to prevent playback from being stopped by a dialog?

Comment: provide a fiddle please

Comment: maybe also browser-dependent behaviour

Comment: I've discovered that if i create the audio using  `var myAudio = new Audio('alarm.mp3');` then the code doesn't work, however if I have an audio tag in my html with src attribute "alarm.mp3", and i instead use var `myAudio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");` then it works the way I want, any ideas why that is?

Comment: I have made a new question for this issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463752/javascript-audio-object-vs-html5-audio-tag

Comment: Do you need to use a dialogue?